# How long double fits so many characters in just 12 bytes?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

How long double fits so many characters in just 12 bytes?

I made an example, a C ++ factorial
when entering a large number, 1754 for example it calculates with a number that apparently would not fit a long double type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    long double fatorial = 1;
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i)
    {
        fatorial *= i;
    }

    string s = to_string(fatorial);
    cout << "Factorial of " << n << " = " <<fatorial << " = " << s;
    return 0;
}
```

**Important note:**
GCC Compiler on Windows, by visual Studio long double behaves like a double

**The problem is how is it stored or the to_string function?**
[image]

Comment: Note the result is not entirely accurate, since the factorial of any integer which is at least 5 must end in a zero.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2706851/1896169

Comment: `long double` seems the wrong data type for this..

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45073141/1896169

Comment: It's very easy to write a large number with very few digits. 2 to the power of 1000, is a very big number with roughly 300 digits but I wrote it using only five digits. Well that's exactly how long double does it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are floating point numbers are stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644699/how-are-floating-point-numbers-are-stored-in-memory)

Comment: @jxh No, it's specified to do this. [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) acts like [`sprintf(buf, "%Lf", d)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), which has a default precision of 6 digits after the decimal place.

Comment: Interesting: I duplicated the result online here: http://cpp.sh/5msos

Comment: Not sure why the link broke.  Limit on number of executions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::to_string(factorial)` will return a string containing the same result as `std::sprintf(buf, "%Lf", value)`.

In turn, `%Lf` prints the entire integer part of a `long double`, a period and 6 decimal digits of the fractional part.

Since `factorial` is a very large number, you end up with a very long string.

However, note that this has nothing to do with `long double`. A simpler example with e.g. `double` is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::to_string(1e300) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
10000000000000000525047602 [...300 decimal digits...] 540160.000000
```

The decimal digits are not exactly zero because the number is not exactly `1e300` but the closest to it that can be represented in the floating-point type.

Comment: very good this example, simple and to the point, but is this feature because of the correct to_string?

Comment: @Dorathoto To what feature in particular are you referring to?

Comment: that it is not only zeros in 1e300 (should have 300 zeros)

Comment: @Dorathoto No, that is a feature of the language. When you use a literal, the compiler will use (one of) the closest values that can be represented in the given type, because you cannot store `1e300` in `double` exactly. So you end up with another value (which has the non-zero digits). Then `std::to_string` is called with that value.

Comment: @jxh No, it cannot be stored exactly. There are algorithms that approximate a decimal representation, but that is not the issue here.

Comment: You're right. `0b1010` raised to the 300th power would require too many bits. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't fit that many characters.  Rather, `to_string` produces that many characters from the data.

Here is a toy program:

```
std::string my_to_string( bool b ) {
  if (b)
    return "This is a string that never ends, it goes on and on my friend, some people started typing it not knowing what it was, and now they still are typing it it just because this is the string that never ends, it goes on and on my friend, some people started typing it not knowing what it was, and now they still are typing it just because...";
  else
    return "no it isn't, I can see the end right ^ there";
}
```

`bool` stores exactly 1 bit of data.  But the string it produces from calling `my_to_string` can be as long as you want.

`double`'s `to_string` is like that.  It generates far more characters than there is "information" in the `double`.

This is because it is encoded as a base 10 number on output.  Inside the `double`, it is encoded as a combination of an unsigned number, a sign bit, and an exponential part.

The "value" is then roughly "1+number/2^constant", times +/- one for the sign, times "2^exponential part".

There are only a certain number of "bits of precision" in base 2; if you printed it in base 2 (or hex, or any power-of-2 base) the double would have a few non-zero digits, then a pile of 0s afterwards (or, if small, it would have 0.0000...000 then a handful of non-zero digits).

But when converted to base 10 there isn't a pile of zero digits in it.

Take 0b10000000 -- aka 2^8.  This is 256 in base 10 -- it has no trailing 0s at all!

Answer (score 1):

This is because floating point numbers only store an approximation of the actual value. If you look at [the actual exact value of `1754!`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1754!) you'll see that your result becomes completely different after the first ~18 digits. The digits after that are just the result of writing (a multiple of) a large power of two in decimal.